# Why isn't the LSTM Model producing same final weights in every run, whereas the inital weights are always same?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6

If you look at the code snippet, we are using the same code for multiple runs with 2000 Epochs and there are no drop outs to avoid the random drops and random weight selections.

But, still we get different results after each run. We checked the initial weights and they are same for each run, i.e. during the start of the run.

In every run we have seen different results.
e.g.: The output shown below depicts that the val_loss is not improving till the last epoch.

```
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0251 - val_loss: 0.0276
1994
--
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0251 - val_loss: 0.0276
1995
--
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0251 - val_loss: 0.0276
1996
--
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0251 - val_loss: 0.0276
1997
--
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0251 - val_loss: 0.0276
1998
--
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0251 - val_loss: 0.0276
1999
--
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0251 - val_loss: 0.0276
[2019-04-07 18:28:17,495 - - DEBUG -my_project_model.py:317 -             fit_lstm() ] Time taken: 126.07314221905544 min
```

And for the same dataset and the same code snippet the outputs are different. The example logs are shown below. And the val_loss is way less than the previous one in just 285 epochs. We are confused what exactly is happening in the background.

```
3s - loss: 0.0044 - val_loss: 0.0011
271
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0043 - val_loss: 0.0011
272
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0043 - val_loss: 0.0011
273
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0043 - val_loss: 9.5030e-04
274
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0042 - val_loss: 9.7404e-04
275
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0042 - val_loss: 0.0010
276
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0044 - val_loss: 9.6836e-04
277
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0042 - val_loss: 0.0011
278
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0042 - val_loss: 0.0010
279
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0042 - val_loss: 0.0010
280
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0042 - val_loss: 0.0011
281
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0042 - val_loss: 8.9629e-04
282
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0041 - val_loss: 9.8693e-04
283
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0041 - val_loss: 9.4584e-04
284
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0041 - val_loss: 0.0011
285
--
Epoch 1/1
Epoch 00000: val_loss did not improve
3s - loss: 0.0041 - val_loss: 9.8990e-04
```

This is understood that it is taking random paths; but the output may match sometime. But it has never matched. We suspected that drop outs may cause more randomness and we removed it from the code snippet. The above results are from Real time example and the code snippet used for the same is given below.

Information on the libraies

```
[id@ip~]$ source activate projectcondaenv

(projectcondaenv) [id@ip~]$ conda list | grep -i keras
dist-keras                0.2.1                     <pip>
keras                     2.0.5                    py36_0  

(projectcondaenv) [id@ip~]$ conda list | grep -i tensor
tensorflow                1.3.0                         0  
tensorflow-base           1.3.0            py36h5293eaa_1  
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.1.5                    py36_0
```

The variables are read form a config file and they are as below:

```
nb_epoch=2000
batch_size=1
neurons=15
```

Code is as shown below:

```py
from numpy.random import seed
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
#from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
#from keras.constraints import NonNeg
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
#from time import time

from exceptions.model_file_not_found_exception import  ModelFileNotFoundException
from exceptions.data_not_found_exception import  DataNotFoundException


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

tf.set_random_seed(1234)
seed(1)


class MyProject(object):
    def fit_lstm(self, train, batch_size, nb_epoch, neurons, test=None, load_model=False):
        import timeit
        try:
            start = timeit.default_timer()
            X, y = train[:, 0:-1], train[:, -1]
            X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])

            if test.any():
                X_test, y_test = test[:, 0:-1], test[:, -1]
                X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])

            model = Sequential()
            model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True,
                           return_sequences=True))
            #model.add(Dropout(self.dropout_1)) #commented
            model.add(LSTM(neurons, stateful=True))
            #model.add(Dropout(self.dropout_2)) #commented
            model.add(Dense(1))
            model.compile(loss=self.loss, optimizer=self.optimizer)

            if load_model:
                pass

                # callbacks
            c = [
                ModelCheckpoint(self.checkpoint_dir+self.model_filename, save_best_only=True,
                                                monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, period=1),
                EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=1),
                ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=self.min_lr)
            ]

            for i in range(nb_epoch):
                print(i)
                model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                          callbacks=c)
                model.reset_states()
            time_taken = timeit.default_timer() - start
            logger.debug('Time taken: ' + str(time_taken/60) + ' min')
            model = self.get_latest_model()
            return model, round(time_taken/60, 2)
        except Exception as err:
            logger.error('Fit LSTM Method failed with Errors .. '+str(err))
            logger.exception('=== Failed to fit the LSTM Model  === ')
            raise err
```

*Can anyone please highlight what could be the issue?*

*Why is there a huge randomness in the output?*

### *Is it not able to find the global minima and stuck at the local minima? Please put some lights to help us move further.*

*I have already referred few articles and Keras issues (as shown below). But none of those answers the questions.*

Reference:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255105/why-is-the-validation-accuracy-fluctuating

There are few Keras issues revolving around:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1597

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2711

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11371

Comment: How do you choose your validation dataset? Is the seed set up correctly?

Comment: _The Validation dataset is always fixed._

We have 830 rows in total and these are Time Series data. 

The first 816 records are used for Training. [Always, and it's fixed]

The last 14 records are used for validation set. And we forecast/predict the next 14 days/records.

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have tried to make reproducible results using `Tensorflow 2.0` and it's high-level `keras` API and let me start by saying it's not an easy task.

I think you are on the wrong track here (though I cannot verify it directly) and the problem is **inherit source of randomness** in Tensorflow.

FIrst of all, you should try to set everything to be as deterministic as possible, to do so, please follow [Keras FAQ section on reproducibility](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development). In essence you have to set up something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn

SEED=0

# Numpy fixed random seed
np.random.seed(SEED)

# Python's random generator
rn.seed(SEED)

# Tensorflow has to use one thread (multiple threads might give you different results)
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                              inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

from keras import backend as K

# Set Tensorflow random seed
tf.set_random_seed(1234)

# Create default graph without parallelism
K.set_session(tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf))
```

Additionally, **you have to** set environment variable `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` before running your Python script from CLI like this:

```
$ PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python my_script.py
```

If you still do not get reproducible results, `CUDA` might be the one to blame. Just to be sure it's not disable it as well (just for testing purposes):

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python my_script.py
```

You may introduce each change step by step in order to remove non-deterministic factors as much as possible. I would go like this:

- Set all seeds and `PYTHONHASHSEED` and check whether results differ
- Use `session_conf` to remove parallelism between operations
- Finally disable CUDA (if previous actions did not help)

Other than that (given you are running the model with the same initial weights and validation split is always the same), it might be an inherent design fault of those frameworks [see this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2743).

Comment: Even after fixing the seed, the final weights are different. The Val_Loss gets stuck sometimes and does not improve. The same code makes it improved in the later runs. Why is itso erratic? I want to understand that.

I want to understand the reason behind huge randomness after fixing the seed and the initial weights (with removal of drop puts too)

Comment: Are you sure you are training from initial weights each run? Maybe you are training for `N` epochs, saving model, loading it afterwards and training it for `N` epochs again (which would explain why after each run your loss is smaller), effectively training for `2*N` epochs?

Comment: Yes. I tried printing the initial weights and all are same in each iteration. As I call Early stopping for each epoch i.e. 2000 times in total so monitor the val_loss happens 2000 times and still it stucks at the local minima.I am using the Stochastic Gradient Descent training algorithm for neural networks. Here one row of data is exposed to the network at a time as input.

Comment: The network has a visible layer with 1 input, a hidden layer with 15 (neurons) LSTM blocks or neurons, and an output layer that makes a single value prediction (with a linear activation function). The default tanh activation function is used for the LSTM blocks. The network is trained for 2000 epochs and a batch size of 1 is used.

Comment: I'm sorry than, I was unable to set Tensorflow to fully deterministic mode either. If the above does not help I am unfortunately as lost as you are (maybe someone else has an answer).